# How to create Jquery UI Accordion with multilevel and keep it open on active page

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I need help on how to create `jquery ui accordion` with multilevel and keep it open on active page. I've successfully used `jquery ui accordion` with one level only. but when I added the next level,  the child window always close when clicked

And the last question is how to keep the accordion open on reload page after I click the list ? I've tried the "active" but with no luck :(

This is my html code :

```
<ul class="accordion">
<h3>Hardware</h3>
<li>
    <ul class="accordion2">
        <li>
            <h3>Monitor</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Monitor Tube</li>
                <li>Monitor LCD</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>PC</li>
        <li>Keyboard</li>
        <li>Mouse</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<h3>Software</h3>
<li>
    <ul class="accordion2">
        <li>Unix</li>
        <li>Linux</li>
        <li>Windows</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and this is my jquery function code :

```
    $(function() {
    $(".accordion").accordion({
        header: "h3",
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".accordion2").accordion({
        header: "h3",           
        autoHeight: false,
        navigation: true,
    });
});
```

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daftar/CYfzZ/).